# Asynchronous function with multiple params

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, executorservice

I currently have the following coding:

```
outputData = parseData(in_data, category, lastKey, firstKey);
return outputData.indexOf("true");
```

parseData would return a ArrayList.outputData is an ArrayList.

I wanted to convert the code above to run asynchronously because parseData is taking a lot of time to process.

My main questions are:

- I need a solution for asynchronous processing that takes in multiple
  variables and output ArrayList
- The second line of codes can't be execute until the parseData is
  completed asynchronously.

What is the methods that I can use to convert the codes above which takes in multiple params and output directly to a variable as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

here is some way you can do that:

1. [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask): you can make your params in an object, then you can use it
2. HandlerThread
3. JobScheduler

   > This is an API for scheduling various types of jobs against the framework that will be executed in your application's own process.

for details, you can see this  [blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129)

4. `ExecutorService` and `Handler` to realize the function
5. you can also use the [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) solution to realize that function.you can read this [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-e52ed7ef32e2) to learn it.

if the task does not need too much time, you can use `AsyncTask`, because it is easy to use

Comment: `AsyncTask` will be deprecated soon, not the best option.

Comment: @art what is the best solution as an alternative to asynctask?

Comment: @Calvin you haven't describe your particular case enough to give reasonable answer, but with what we have I think `RxJava`

Comment: @art, I have edit my question, not sure whether it is clear enough with this edit.

Comment: @Calvin where do you call `parseData` method now? Somewhere in activity or fragment, or maybe ViewModel or Presenter? Or maybe it is some background task. There is [the guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) which can help you to choose appropriate solution. If it won't be enough for you, then it would be better if you show more of your code here, the link to github repo is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the code to  run asynchronously and to write the result to the variable  `outputData` some time later, after finishing all the computations.
First, if `outputData` is a local variable, this is simply impossible.
Second, if `outputData` is a field, this is possible, but not convenient: when you eventually want to use that value, how do you know that the asynchronous computation has completed? So to cope with this situation interface `java.util.concurrent.Future` was designed.

The usual approach to call such isolated asynchronous code is to use `ExecutorService.submit(Callable)` which returns `Future`. When you need the result of computation, you call `Future.get()` and wait until the result is computed:

```
ExecutorService pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool(); // or use any other ExecutorService 
Callable<ArrayList> function = ()->parseData(in_data, category, lastKey, firstKey);
Future<ArrayList> future = pool.submit(function); // computation started in parallel, we can do other work
...
ArrayList res = future.get(); // when we eventually need the result of asynchronous computation
```

Comment: I try out your code, and Android Studio is flagging the following error: "Unhandled exceptions: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException, java.lang.InterruptedException" at the line "future.get();" on ,get()

Comment: surround it with try-catch, or mark enclosing method as "throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException".